# Why UI panel in Unity doesn't work for me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two panels on canvas. The first one is for the Game Over window and it works after the player's destroyed. The second one is for Pause Game it works after pressing the button Escap and it has two buttons one for resume and the second for quit.

The problem is when I press the button Continue it doesn't work and when I press the Quit it reloads the game.

I checked the functions onClick, and both are ok for quit and continue.

Below are screenshots for the pause window and buttons:

[Pause Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV6Tl.png)

[Function on resume button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWuWa.png)

[Function on quit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2gPY.png)

Below is the code of Pause Window:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIManagerPause : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pauseGame;
    bool isPaused;
    public CanvasGroup pauseWindow;
    public float TimeToFade = 1f;
    public bool fadeIn1 = false;
    public bool fadeOut2 = false;

    bool disableEscapeButton;

    private void Start()
    {
        //gameOverMenu.SetActive(false);
        isPaused = false;
        disableEscapeButton = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PauseGame());
        if (fadeIn1 == true)
        {
            if (pauseWindow.alpha < 1)
            {
                pauseWindow.alpha += TimeToFade * Time.deltaTime;
                if (pauseWindow.alpha >= 1)
                {
                    fadeIn1 = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fadeOut2 == true)
        {
            if (pauseWindow.alpha >= 0)
            {
                pauseWindow.alpha -= TimeToFade * Time.deltaTime;
                if (pauseWindow.alpha == 0)
                {
                    fadeOut2 = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    IEnumerator PauseGame()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
            if (isPaused && !disableEscapeButton)
            {
                FadeIn1();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                disableEscapeButton = true;
            }
            if (!isPaused && disableEscapeButton)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                FadeOut2();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
                disableEscapeButton = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        FadeOut2();
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void FadeIn1()
    {
        fadeIn1 = true;
    }

    public void FadeOut2()
    {
        fadeOut2 = true;
    }

}
```

Below id the code of Game over window:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameOverMenu;
    public Texture2D BoxBorder;

     FadeInOut GameOverFade;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameOverFade = GetComponent<FadeInOut>();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PlayerHealth.onPlayerDeath += EnablegameOverMenu;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerHealth.onPlayerDeath -= EnablegameOverMenu;
    }

    public void EnablegameOverMenu()
    {       
        GameOverFade.FadeIn();
    }

    public void RestartGame()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RestartLevel());
    }

    IEnumerator RestartLevel()
    {
        GameOverFade.FadeOut();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
        Application.Quit();
    }

}
```

in the beginning, the code was in one file then I separated it into files but also the problem is the same. I was expecting that when I press on the continue button the game will resume and when  I press on the quit button I'll exit the game.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors

Comment: Is the object that `UIManagerPause` on enabled?

Comment: Why are you doing `StartCoroutine(PauseGame());` **every frame** in `Update`? This will run hundreds of concurrent routines ... sounds to me like the entire thing happening in `Update` should rather happen in the coroutine and only the keyboard check should happen in `Update`

Comment: @CoderMuffin  Yes, it is enabled and the script is on canvas. I also noticed if I changed the sorting in the Hierarchy the last one works for example if the pause before gameover object it doesn't work and if I put it after gameover it works and game over doesn't work. very strange.

Comment: @derHugo I have no a lot experience in Unity. Where I have to put it?

Comment: @Fahad you should move if statement from the coroutine and put it in update instead like this: (`if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {StartCoroutine(PauseGame());}` :)

Comment: @CoderMuffin I have moved it, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so where do I start, first of all, what you are doing with starting a coroutine every frame isn't ideal. In most cases you'd probably want to do this stuff in void Update() but not like you did. But if you want to make it with a coroutine you should make a Coroutine that you call one time in void Start() like this:

```
IEnumerator PauseGame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (isPaused)
                Resume(); //Close Pause Menu
            else
                Pause(); //Open Pause Menu
        }
        yield return null;
    }
 }
    
 public void Pause()
 {
    //Do whatever you want to pause
 }
 public void Resume()
 {
    //Do whatever you want to Resume
 }
```

Also you should use Coroutines for the Fade Stuff like this:

```
IEnumerator Fade(float startValue, float goalValue)
{
    pauseWindow.alpha = startValue;
    if (goalValue > startValue)
    {
        while (pauseWindow.alpha != goalValue && pauseWindow.alpha < goalValue)
        {
            pauseWindow.alpha += TimeToFade * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (pauseWindow.alpha != goalValue && pauseWindow.alpha > goalValue)
        {
            pauseWindow.alpha -= TimeToFade * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    pauseWindow.alpha = goalValue;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

And you would call the Fade like this:

```
public void FadeIn() => StartCoroutine(Fade(1, 0));
public void FadeOut() => StartCoroutine(Fade(0, 1));
```

But regarding the Application.Quit, it only works in a app build, I'm guessing that the UnityEngine.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false is to stop the game also in the Engine, but you should put this before it #if UNITY_EDITOR and this after it #endif so there will occur no errors when having a build.

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem with my code above is the button continue, everything works except the button continue. I changed the starting of coroutine in update like this; ```        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) { StartCoroutine(PauseGame()); }
```

Comment: Okay, soo first, I would really recommend using the Coroutine for the fade effect, but then the reason the Continue Button doesn't work, is that your code only stops and shows the pause menu when Clicking Escape, I would recommend you to move the complete code for pausing and resuming you have in the if statement into an own method and then call it in the if statement. But It's kind of hard to explain it here because of the word limit, feel free to add me on Discord GlitchDev#4875, then I can explain that in a call.

Comment: I sent you a request